# ASP.NET with jQueryUI: server side event not firing

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I have an ASP.NET page where the page is making use of jQuery UI dialog. When a user is clicking a button (`btnGo`) in a page, I will check if the user is logged in or not. If not logged in, I would show the jQuery UI dialog to login. I used this code:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
   <br />  
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtModelId" runat="server" Text="12"></asp:TextBox><br />

   <asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="btnGo_Click" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblUserMsg" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></div>
    <div id="divContentHolder">
    <div class="demo">

    <div id="dialog" title="Login with your User Account">
    <p id="validateTips">Enter your EmailId & password</p>


    <fieldset>

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" CssClass="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
  <!-- &nbsp;<asp:Button   ID="btnSingIn" runat="server" OnClick="btnSingIn_Click" Text="Button" /><br />-->
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
    </fieldset>

    </div><!--dialog-->
    </div><!--demo-->
   </div><!--divContentHolder-->

</form>
```

And on the server side:

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckUserLoggedIn();
    }

private void CheckUserLoggedIn()
    {
        if (Session["username"] != null)
        {
            Response.Write("Logged in user");
            ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("isAuthenticated", "true");
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("isAuthenticated", "false");
        }
    }
```

The above code works fine somewhat. If a user is not logged in, it will show the 
jQuery UI Dialog to login. But the problem is, The server side function `btnLogin_Click()` (Click event of ASP.NET button `btnLogin`) is not getting fired. I tried it in another test page by placing a form tag just before the fieldset and it worked.
Ex:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <fieldset>  then  rest of the items...(text box and button)
```

But I can't do this in the first page, because if I place the form tag just before the field set, my Other ASP.NET text box and button would be out of the form and when trying to run it is showing an error, telling that the txt box control has to be in the form.

I know we can't use multiple forms in this page with `runat="server"`.

Whats the solution for this problem?

The javascript code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    var name = $("#name"),
        email = $("#email"),
        password = $("#password"),
        allFields = $([]).add(name).add(email).add(password),
        tips = $("#validateTips");

    function updateTips(t) {
        tips.text(t).effect("highlight",{},1500);
    }

    function checkLength(o,n,min,max) {

        if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
            o.addClass('ui-state-error');
            updateTips("Length of " + n + " must be between "+min+" and "+max+".");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    function checkRegexp(o,regexp,n) {

        if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
            o.addClass('ui-state-error');
            updateTips(n);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Create an account': function() {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass('ui-state-error');

                bValid=true;
                if (bValid) {

                    /*$('#users tbody').append('<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + name.val() + '</td>' + 
                        '<td>' + email.val() + '</td>' + 
                        '<td>' + password.val() + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>'); */

                        alert("Check User Credentials")
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');
        }
    });



    $('#create-user').click(function() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    })
    .hover(
        function(){ 
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover"); 
        },
        function(){ 
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover"); 
        }
    ).mousedown(function(){
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-active"); 
    })
    .mouseup(function(){
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-active");
    });

//});
var isAuthenticated = $("#isAuthenticated").val();
if (isAuthenticated && isAuthenticated == "false")
{
// Display the modal dialog.
$("#dialog").dialog("open");
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where's the JavaScript?!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try setting `UseSubmitBehavior=false` on the button control. Apparently the jQuery BlockUI widget changes the button behavior and it doesn't submit correctly.

See: http://encosia.com/2008/10/04/using-jquery-to-enhance-aspnet-ajax-progress-indication/

Comment: But in server side, I am getting the Value filled in ASP.NET text box controls as null
Ex : txtFirstName.Text

Any idea ?

Comment: Yeah I had the same thing happen, Shyju.  I ended up following the link in vondip's answer and changing the way I show the dialog with jQuery:

var dlg = $("#AddEditDialog").dialog({ modal: true });
dlg.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));

Comment: This solved my problem of Jquery Dialog and asp:button inside of dialog.. It wasn't submitting.. took me a while to get here

Answer (score 2):

well use these instructions, I found them very helpful:

http://relativelypositioned.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/jquery-dialog-aspnet-no-postback/

and specifically:

```
uiDialog.parent().appendTo('/html/body/form[0]');
```