# How to avoid postback of parent page while using modal popup extender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, postback, modalpopup

I have a page which have a modalpopup. While i change the selected value of the dropdownlist in modalpopup, the whole page refreshes (ie. the parent page) and the controls below the popup blinks.
My requirement is to avoid this postback of the parent page while selecting some control from the popup control. How can i achieve this using ajax modalpopup control?

My modal popup is within an update panel.

Regards,
Sujith.S

Answer (score 1):

On `dropdownlist` set
`Autopostback = "false"`

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your `dropdownlist` in `updatepanel` to avoid full postback

Answer (score 0):

U can use :

**Jquery**

or

**Ajax**

Look to this [about popup window in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996499/about-popup-window-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

Put your modal popup in updatepanel